# Intellij IDEA Error: Could not find or load main class test

Tags: java, maven, debugging, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA for learning automation testing with `Selenium` and have write 3/4 maven tests in my TestSuite using `TestNG` annotations.

Now on `Run/Debug` Config in `VM option` If I use command

```
-Dbrowser="chrome"
```

run the test suite, it works fine.

But when I need to run a specific test I try giving the command

```
-Dtest=TestSuit#testname
```

to test and run but it gives an erro as

> Error: Could not find or load main class test.

I have already tried deleting target folder and run again.
Also, java path is already set correctly.

[image: Configurations]

Comment: anyone can help please

Comment: TestSuit is your class name or what is suite?

Comment: yes TestSuit is my classname. there is no suite

Comment: see in picture. when in VM options i runt without [code]-Dtest=useronHomepage test[/code] all test runs ok but when i try to run specific test it gives error as mention in tital

Comment: in new version of intellij individual test runs under method section so its my mistake that i understand wrong. Admin can close this discussion @niharika_neo Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

This one is extremely wierd, i added -DrunSequence=false and I got this very same error, made no sense, removed the -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m, instead put -Dmyproperty=myproperty...suddenly no error, put back the -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m options and change the -D option back to the original and now everything is working, why was it not working earlier and complaining with Could not load main class...is one of the things that will never go explained.
Cheers,
Vipin.